# how to retrieve x random records from a table with record no in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following query is returning top 24 random records like below

```
SELECT top 24
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QuestionID) AS QuestionNo,
    Q.QuestionID,
    CS.Section
FROM Questions Q
left join dbo.ChapterSection CS
    on Q.SectionID=CS.SectionID
order by newid()

74  656      Section 3.1 - A long and illustrious history- Early Briton
183 765      Section 3.3 - A long and illustrious history-The Tudors and Stuarts
432 1017     Section 4.5 - A modern, thriving society - Arts and culture
```

What I want is QuestionNo to have values from 1 to 24 as below

```
1   656     Section 3.1 - A long and illustrious history- Early Briton
2   765     Section 3.3 - A long and illustrious history-The Tudors and Stuarts
3   1017    Section 4.5 - A modern, thriving society - Arts and culture
```

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ni) QuestionNo
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 24 *, newid() ni
    FROM Table
    order by newid()
    )t
```

OR

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn), *
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 24 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY newid()) rn
    FROM Table
    ) t
```

Comment: This would order the QuestionNo like 300,301,302 etc but I want the record no to start from 1 followed by 2,3,4...24

Comment: @Learner then you dont need row_number in the inner SELECT. You just get top 24 ordered bu newid and use ROW_NUMBER in the outer statement.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `ORDER BY` in subqueries.